# Cannot find element I want to click - selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate updating a service desk ticket upon receipt of an E-mail. I've already figured out the way to 'listen' for an E-mail and launch the website/login, however for the life of me one of the parts I thought would be the easiest is proving to be the most difficult. Essentially I need to click the dropdown in the image below and either type or click the option 'Acknowledged'.

Service desk photo with drop down options :

[image]

Here is the snippet of code for the drop down, note: the number in the ID in the code changes based on the ticket (in this example the number is 298)

```
<tr>
<td id="td_298_status">
<div id="298_status" class="dropdown-wrapper add-scroll autosuggest get-values-on-open hiddendropdown formField opened">
<select class="selectedKeysValues" style="display:none" id="status" name="status">
<option value="1" selected="">New</option>
</select>

<span class="dd-description"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openAdvancedSearchForComboBox('SelectFilterValues.jsp?func=updateComboBox&amp;fromComboBox=YES&amp;dbValueField=11587&amp;dbCaptionField=12868&amp;dbTable=20130&amp;comboboxId=status&amp;moduleRelevance=16');">Advanced Search</a></span>
<select class="custom_select" style="display:none" name="status_CustomSelect" id="status_CustomSelect">
</select><div class="newListSelected status_CustomSelect" tabindex="0"><input type="text" class="autoSuggestInput" value="" style="width: 156px;"><div class="selectedTxt"><span class="defaultText">New</span></div><div class="containerContentDiv" style="width: auto; top: 25px;"><div class="jScrollPaneContainer" style="display: block;"><div class="scroll_pane" id="addScroll_status_CustomSelect" style="display: block; height: 202px; top: 0px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;"><ul class="newList" style="left: 0px; display: block;"><li class="option_0_option">Please select a status</li><li class="option_1_option selected hiLite">New</li><li class="option_3_option">Closed</li><li class="option_4_option">Submit Error</li><li class="option_5_option">Pending</li><li class="option_7_option">Deleted</li><li class="option_11_option">Request Rejected</li><li class="option_37_option">Work In Progress</li><li class="option_38_option">Resolved</li><li class="option_39_option">Acknowledged</li></ul></div></div><div class="addedDescription" style="display: block;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openAdvancedSearchForComboBox('SelectFilterValues.jsp?func=updateComboBox&amp;fromComboBox=YES&amp;dbValueField=11587&amp;dbCaptionField=12868&amp;dbTable=20130&amp;comboboxId=status&amp;moduleRelevance=16');">Advanced Search</a></div></div></div>
<span class="afterSelectJS" style="display:none">closureInformationCheck();StatusChange();</span>
</div>
</td>
<td id="closureInformationTD" style="display: none;"><table id="closureInformationTable"><tbody><tr><td class="Form_Ctrl_Label">Closure Information</td>
<td id="td_298_closureInformation" style="padding-left:25px;">
<div id="298_closureInformation" class="dropdown-wrapper add-scroll autosuggest get-values-on-open hiddendropdown formField">
<select class="selectedKeysValues" style="display:none" id="closureInformation" name="closureInformation">
<option value="0" selected="">None</option>
</select>

<span class="dd-description"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openAdvancedSearchForComboBox('SelectFilterValues.jsp?func=updateComboBox&amp;fromComboBox=YES&amp;dbValueField=11587&amp;dbCaptionField=12868&amp;dbTable=21229&amp;comboboxId=closureInformation');">Advanced Search</a></span>
<select class="custom_select" style="display:none" name="closureInformation_CustomSelect" id="closureInformation_CustomSelect">
</select><div class="newListSelected closureInformation_CustomSelect" tabindex="0"><input type="text" class="autoSuggestInput" value="" style="display: none;"><div class="selectedTxt"><span class="defaultText">None</span></div><div class="containerContentDiv"><div class="jScrollPaneContainer" style="display: none;"><div class="scroll_pane" id="addScroll_closureInformation_CustomSelect" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; display: none;"><ul class="newList" style="left: 0px; display: none;"></ul></div></div><div class="addedDescription" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openAdvancedSearchForComboBox('SelectFilterValues.jsp?func=updateComboBox&amp;fromComboBox=YES&amp;dbValueField=11587&amp;dbCaptionField=12868&amp;dbTable=21229&amp;comboboxId=closureInformation');">Advanced Search</a></div></div></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
```

I've tried a whole bunch fo things like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="298_status"]/div/input').click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//td[contains(text(), '_status')]")
```

But I always get errors stating that the element cant be found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might want to interact with the `select` element. They work differently from all other elements, and there is a specific Selenium library for handling them. Here is probably the most straightforward way to accomplish what you're trying to do. Caveat though, I'm not sure why the element is not being found on the web page -- that is the first thing you'll have to get answered. For that, I'd make sure it is scrolled into view, if it is not visible by default when the page is rendered. You may have a timeout issue, etc.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

timeout = 15
try:
    status_select = WebDriverWait(self.thread.driver, timeout).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(("id", "status"))
    )
    Select(status_select).select_by_value("Acknowledged")
except:
    print("Element was not visible on page after", timeout, "seconds.")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared and you `need to click the dropdown in the image below and click the option` **Acknowledged** you can use the following code block :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='newListSelected status_CustomSelect']/input[@class='autoSuggestInput' and @type='text']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='newListSelected status_CustomSelect']/input[@class='autoSuggestInput' and @type='text']//following::ul[@class='newList']/li[@class='option_39_option']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

From your HTML code, I can know what you want to operated is not a native select (use Tag `<select>` `<option>`) of HTML, actually it's a simulated select (which UI and behaviour looks like a native select).

In order to operate simulated select, you need to do following steps:

1. Figure out click on which element will display all options
2. Figure out the HTML code of all options, so that you can write locator to find the option you want to choose.

From your HTML code, I can't exactly know the html code of element said in above step 1. But from the screenshot, I guess the down arrow besides 'Please select a status' should be we wanted.

From your HTML code, I can find the HTML code of all options, they are here:

```html
<ul class="newList" style="left: 0px; display: block;">
 <li class="option_0_option">Please select a status</li>
 <li class="option_1_option selected hiLite">New</li>
 <li class="option_3_option">Closed</li>
 <li class="option_4_option">Submit Error</li>
 <li class="option_5_option">Pending</li>
 <li class="option_7_option">Deleted</li>
 <li class="option_11_option">Request Rejected</li>
 <li class="option_37_option">Work In Progress</li>
 <li class="option_38_option">Resolved</li>
 <li class="option_39_option">Acknowledged</li>
</ul>
```

We have to split into two steps in code to choose the option:

1. Click the down arrow to make all options visible (Because selenium can't click on invisible element).
2. Click the 'Acknowledged' option

Python code example:

```
// find down arrow and click, please complete this part by yourself
// if you have difficult to do that, please tell me the exact HTML code of the down arrow 
driver.find_element_by_xxx('xxxxxxxxxx').click();

// find option to click (there are two ways)
1) if only one element's text is 'Acknowledged' in whole page
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='Acknowledged']").click()
2) otherwise
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[li[text='Please select a status']]/li[text()='Acknowledged']").click()
```